# Jquery animation of height width not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I've created this simple animation using jQuery. But event doesn't trigger the animation where I expand the div height and width.

```
$('img').click(function(){
    $('.popup').animate({'height': '+= 100px','width':'+=100px' })
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fg5h4/)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the space between `+=` and `100px` when changing your `height`:

```
$('img').click(function(){
    $('.popup').animate({'height': '+=100px','width':'+=100px' })
})
//-----------------------------------^ here
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fg5h4/3/)

Note: I'm sure you know, but you won't see any effect whilst the div has the property `display:none`

Comment: You should also mention to remove `display:none` from `.popup`.

Comment: @Vucko Was editing. But would have thought that was quite obvious.